# Como abrir uma popup com tamanho total da tela em monitores extendidos?

Tags: javascript

Estou com um cenário onde são utilizadas duas TVs extendidas na vertical para exibir uma lista de pedidos.
Estou tentando abrir uma popup que fique com o tamanho total da tela das duas TVs, mas, mesmo colocando a altura como 3840px o popup só abre preenchendo a primeira tela.
Alguma sugestão?

```
function popitup(a) {
window.open(a,'open_window','height=3840, left=1, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no, top=1, width=1080,fullscreen=yes');}
```

A aplicação em si utiliza java com spring mvc e thymeleaf no front end. O trecho acima é javascript para abrir o popup.

Comment: Sugestão: faça uma aplicação windows. Você terá muito mais controle e poderá fazer coisas que uma aplicação web não pode. Fica bem mais fácil brincar com multitelas também.

Comment: Utilize `window.innerWidth`

Comment: window.innerWidth e window.innerHeight só retornam o tamanho de uma das telas e não o total das duas.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar usar as funções:

- screen.availWidth
- screen.availHeight
- screen.width
- screen.height

Exemplo:

```
function popitup(a) {
window.open(a,'open_window','height=screen.height, left=1, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no, top=1, width=screen.width,fullscreen=yes');}
```

Comment: o problema é que gostaria que a tela já abrisse ocupando a área das duas TVs, já que elas estão na mesma máquina e configuradas como monitores extendidos. Da forma que você sugeriu, a função só recupera o tamanho de uma das telas.